# Flutter CheckBoxList is not selecting

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I have a ListViewBuilder with data from Firestore. In my list I want return a ListTile and add CheckBox to the ListTile or return a CheckBoxListTile whichever works better.
But for some reasons, which I can tell, I can't select the checkbox in both cases.

When I return a ListTile with the checkbox with single checkbox value, it checks all the boxes when I select only one. When I try set it to multiple check with `checkList = []`, nothing selects at all

When I return a CheckBoxListTile, I am not able to select anything either. Can someone help me with this, please. I've been stuck for ages.

**This is my code for returning CheckBoxListTile**

```
List<int> selectedList = [];
List<bool> isCheckedList = [];

StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore....
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final info = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  isCheckedList =
                      List.filled(snapshot.data!.docs.length, false);
                  var timestamp = info.get("Time") as Timestamp;
                  final isRead = info.get("Read");

                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                    checkColor: Colors.green,
                    tileColor: isRead == "No" ? Colors.teal.shade100 : null,
                    title: TextScroll(
                      "${info.get("title")}.  ",
                      velocity: const Velocity(pixelsPerSecond: Offset(30, 0)),
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    value: isCheckedList[index],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        isCheckedList[index] = value!;
                        if (value) {
                          selectedList.add(index);
                        } else {
                          selectedList.remove(index);
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }

            return Center(
              child: Text("Whatever"),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `isChecked` List declaration outside the ListView builder. Right now, it's causing all checkboxes to reset when one is checked due to its placement within the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedList` and `isCheckedList` are moved to the state of the Build widget. This way, the state is maintained even when the build method is called again. Make sure to replace FirebaseFirestore.... with your actual stream. This should fix the issue you're experiencing with selecting checkboxes in your list.

Comment: I did that but it's still not checking